# Parameter 0 of constructor in controller required a bean of type repository class from another package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

although i have added the package containing my GemDaoImpl repository class in pom.xml, it is giving error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bfm.accounting.portfolio.controller.PortfolioApiController required a bean of type 'com.bfm.app.reporting.gem.dao.impl.GemDaoImpl' that could not be found.
    
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bfm.app.reporting.gem.dao.impl.GemDaoImpl' in your configuration.
```

Can you please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

try mentioning the package that contains the GemDaoImpl in component-scan element in XML

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.customer" />
```

or in case if you are using class-based configuration the use

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"list of packages"})
```